# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED using Docker network to communicate between a backend container and a React container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, socket.io, docker-network

I have a backend up (NodeJS) which is the listening on some port (2345 in this example). 
The client application is a React app. Both are leveraging `socket.io` in order to communicate between themselves. Both are containerized.
I then run them both on the same network, using the "network" flag:

`docker run -it --network=test1 --name serverapp server-app
docker run -it --network=test1 client-app`

In the client, I have this code (in the server the code is pretty standard, almost copy-paste from socket.io page):

```
const socket = io.connect('http://serverapp:2345');
socket.emit('getData');
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('got data: ${data}');
  })
```

What I suspect is that the problem has to do with having the client (React) app served by the `http-server` package, and then in the browser context, the hostname is not understood and therefore cannot be resolved. When I go into the browser console, I then see the following error: **GET http://tbserver:2345/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MzyGQLT net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

Now if I switch (in the client-app) the hostname `serverapp` to localhost (which the browser understands but is not recommended to use in docker as it is interpreted differently), when trying to connect to the server socket, I get the error: **GET http://localhost:2345/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MzyFyAe net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.

Another piece of information is that we currently **build the React app** (using `npm run build`), **and then** we build and run the Docker container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY /app/build/. /app/.
EXPOSE 2974 2326 1337 2324 7000 8769 8000 2345
CMD ["http-server", "-p", "8000"]`
```

(So, no build of the React app takes place while building the container; we rather rely on a prebuilt once)

Not sure what I am missing here and if it has to do with the `http-server` or not, but prior to that I managed to get a fully working `socket.io` connection between 2 NodeJS applications using the same Docker network, so it shouldn't be a code issue.

Comment: can you wget this address in your docker and see that it works?
`'http://serverapp:2345' `
you may not have the DNS inside the docker

Comment: What do you mean by wget in the docker exactly? You mean by using docker exec?

Comment: run this command inside docker shell

Comment: docker exec -it cdbd wget 'http://serverapp:2345' 
produces:
wget: bad address 'serverapp:2345'

Comment: try to add your domain to etc/hosts like this: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-add-new-host-entry-in-etc-hosts-when-a-docker-container-is-run/
let me know if this works so I will post as answer

Comment: Can you also post the Dockerfile for the server code?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Same issue.. Did someone solve it? @Graham

Answer (score 1):

Your browser needs to know how to resolve the SocketIO server address. You can expose port `2345` of `serverapp` and bind port `2345` of your host to port `2345` of `serverapp`

```
docker run -it --network=test1 -p 2345:2345 --name serverapp server-app
```

That way you can use localhost in your client code

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:2345');
```

Also get rid of `2345` from your client Dockerfile