# Communication problem with dockerized React and Spring Boot App

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker

I have created a simple application with react and spring boot. Now I'm trying to deployed it with docker container. Both react and spring boot are compiled correctly ( containers are working on the same machine ).

React App is visible to the internet ( port 80 of the react app container ), spring boot is published on port 8080 and is not reachable from the outside.
This is the current port mapping:

[image]

The docker compose file is configured as follow:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app_fe:
    image: app_fe:latest
    container_name: app_fe
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 80:3000 
    depends_on:
      - app_be

  app_be:
    image: app_be:latest
    container_name: app_be
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

I've tried all possible ip configuration inside app_fe but is not able to reach the backend of the app when the request comes from the client browser.

The request is completed successfully if it is made from the machine where the containers are published.

Which IP should I configure in the front end or how should I modify the docker compose configuration to make the communication possible?

Comment: You need to link your frontend app to the backend app.
Meaning you are missing `    links:
      - app_be` in your `app_fe` service definition. This allows container to discover each other.

Comment: Then which ip should i configure on the front end for communication? localhost, virtual machine IP address where containers are deployed or IP address of app_be container?

Comment: Sorry, missed that point. Your `app_be` container is accessible by your `app_fe` using `app_be` as target url.

Comment: The React application is probably running in a browser; even if you're serving it from a container, it's actually running on the client's desktop, and it can't use any Docker features.  You need the server's DNS name or IP address (or possibly `localhost`) and the first published `ports:` number to reach the backend.  Maybe see [ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED using Docker network to communicate between a backend container and a React container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617814/err-name-not-resolved-using-docker-network-to-communicate-between-a-backend-cont).

Comment: @DavidMaze so the backend port must be open to the outside? there is no way to keep the communication between containers hidden even when the request comes form client browser?

Comment: This isn't "communication between containers" because the React application is running in the end user's browser.  Using a reverse proxy is common practice an can simplify some deployment steps; that would expose the backend through an `/api` URL path but not directly publish its port; for example [Docker-compose with nginx reverse, a website and a restful api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562017/docker-compose-with-nginx-reverse-a-website-and-a-restful-api)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `links` marked as `legacy feature of Docker`. It may eventually be removed.

https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

> The --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate communication between two containers instead of using --link. One feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with --link is sharing environment variables between containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment variables between containers in a more controlled way.

You can use the network feature to enable the communication between containers.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Here is the updated compose yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app_fe:
    image: app_fe:latest
    container_name: app_fe
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 80:3000 
    depends_on:
      - app_be
    networks:
      - my_apps_network

  app_be:
    image: app_be:latest
    container_name: app_be
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - my_apps_network
    
networks:
  my_apps_network:
    driver: bridge
```

The `app_fe` and `app_be` are connected to the same network. This allows them to communicate with each other using the service names.

**References** :

- [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/)
- [Legacy container links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)
- [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)
- [Bridge network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/)

Comment: Since Compose does provide the `default` network, you don't need to manually specify `networks:` anywhere.

Comment: Communication between containers now work with their service names but the request  still doesn't work when comes from client browser, does the server port 8080 have to be exposed to the outside?

Answer (score -1):

You need to link your `app_fe` to your `app_be`. Linking allows your containers to discover each other.

Regarding this point, your compose file should look like following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app_fe:
    image: app_fe:latest
    container_name: app_fe
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 80:3000 
    depends_on:
      - app_be
    links:
      - app_be

  app_be:
    image: app_be:latest
    container_name: app_be
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: As noted above, `links:` are an obsolete option and you shouldn't recommend them.  Compose sets up Docker networking on its own, so this isn't especially effective; also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't aware of the deprecation. Should update by compose files soon :)